# .Net Standard library using selenium/cefsharp

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, standards, cefsharp

I have created a Windows Forms bot that logins and navigates around a web page, gets some data and clicks some buttons. Until now, I have used cefsharp with cefsharp.winforms to display the browser in the app. I would like to port this functionality to .net standard library, have aspnet core backend that would communicate with the bot and send the data to some fronend (basically I would like to port winforms to web app). 
I would like to have a .net standard library so aspnet core AND win forms could use the same core lib. 
As far as I can tell, cefsharp.offscreen doesn't work with .net standard.

I checked Selenium.WebDriver packet on nuget.org and under dependencies found

```
.NETStandard 2.0
Newtonsoft.Json (>= 12.0.2)
```

Which from my understanding means it should support .net standard 2.0. But when I try to create an object from a class from .net standard 2.0 lib that is using Selenium.WebDriver and ChromeDriver packages from windows forms 4.6.1, I get a runtime error

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.141.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

Code from WinForms 4.6.1 app:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var test = new StandardLib.TestingWebDriver();
    test.TestDriver();
}
```

Code from my StardardLib .net standard 2.0 library project:

```
public class TestingWebDriver
{
    public void TestDriver() {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        Console.WriteLine(driver.PageSource);
    }
}
```

I have been trying different ways to solve this problem the whole day with no success. If you have any idea how to solve this or any alternative I could use instead of cefsharp/selenium, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: I haven't used C# for Selenium before, but part of the problem could be using .net standard.  Microsoft's ".net" terminology is very very confusing... See this link: https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/10/dotnet-core-standard-difference/

Comment: also see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server  It's worth noting that .net core contains and/or is compatible with most .net framework libraries (so .net core can import just about any .net framework library and will contain them all at some point...)  You might also consider using a webview or IE embedded to have the server provide the interface...

Comment: I have read both links but am still confused. It compiles without a problem when selecting "correct" versions for .net standard library and .net framework for winforms. I followed the table at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard. If I understood you correctly, I could make a .net framework lib project and both winforms and asp.net core app could use it? Will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out. So the winforms app was trying to find (seleniums) webdriver.dll inside the winforms /bin/debug folder instead of library's /bin/debug.

**All I had to do is install the same packages that I have inside the standard library to the winforms as well**  and it works!

I assume this is expected workflow (for some reason that I don't understand), someone could elaborate on that. So after all it had nothing to do with .net standard, just me not knowing how to properly use/import class libraries.